# algorithm environment colored by command outside

Tags: floats, color, algorithms

I found algorithm environment produces undesired output in this situation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\newcommand{\colormacro}[1]{{\color{red} [#1]}}

\begin{document}
    \colormacro{colored things long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long 
        long long long long long long}
    \begin{algorithm}[t]
        It is correct here.
        \caption{Title and lines are colored}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like below.

[image]

It does not appear if I replace algorithm with figure or table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the current text colour bleeds into the floating environment since [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) - the package that creates the `algorithm` environment within [`algorithm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) - doesn't reset the colour. This is done by default within the regular floats like `figure` and `table`.

The following patch corrects this behaviour using a similar method employed by `figure` and `table`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\makeatletter
\let\old@float@makebox\float@makebox
\renewcommand{\float@makebox}[1]{%
  \color@vbox\normalcolor
    \old@float@makebox{#1}%
  \color@endbox}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\color{red}%
\lipsum[1-7]

\begin{algorithm}[t]
  It is correct here.
  \caption{Title and lines are colored}
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[7-11]

\end{document}
```